# Using WxLua and need to install miniZip

Tags: lua, wxlua

Im using Wxlua for a GUI im building but need minizip for one of my functions but have no idea how to install minizine to my lua dir.

I expect minizip = require('minizip') to work with my wxlua

Answer (score 0):

`minizip` is not part of wxlua, so you need to follow the instructions from the source you got the package from. For example, [this package](https://luapower.com/minizip) provides all the necessary binaries, but requires LuaJIT or lua+luaffi to run.

Usually, it's sufficient to place binary files (*.so or *.dll) into a folder listed in `package.cpath` and lua files into a folder listed in `package.path`, but those files may have their own dependencies, so it's better to consult documentation for the module.